# Scala simple function returns type mismatch error

Tags: scala

I have a list of vectors. Each vector represents a range in the form of `Vector(Double,Double)`. I wanted to create a function that given an input number, finds in which vector it is contained and returns the index of that vector. I dont know if there is an easier way to do it and i am new to Scala but my code is as follows:

```
val vectors = #List of vectors ( List[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Double]] )

def in_range(start: Double, end: Double, x : Double): Boolean = {(x>= start && x<end)}

def find_index(x:Double): Int = {
    for(i <- 0 to n){
     if( in_range(vectors(i)(0),vectors(i)(1),x)){ 
        return i
     }
}
```

And i get the following error:

```
<console>:28: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
        for(i <- 0 to 10){
              ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `for` terminates without returning a value it will return `Unit` rather than the required `Int`, hence the error message.

But you should look at methods like `find` for this sort of thing, rather than iterating through the indices of a collection. e.g.

```
def find_index(x: Double): Int =
  vectors.indexWhere(v => in_range(v(0), v(1), x))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of errors in your code, let's fix all of them one by one.

The most important one is that there is no `return` in **Scala** *(well, it does exist, but you [shouldn't use it](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html))*.
In **Scala**, the return of a block is the return of its last expression. Thus, in your case, the return of `find_index` is the return of `for(){...}`, which actually isn't a **for loop**, but a [**for comprehension**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html); and if you would have read the [**documentation**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) you would known that it desugars to a simple `foreach` call, which returns `Unit`, not `Int`.

So, you may trick the compiler with this:

```
def find_index(x:Double): Int = {
    for(i <- 0 to n){
     if( in_range(vectors(i)(0),vectors(i)(1),x)){ 
        return i
     }
     -1 // default return value.
}
```

But that is just a bad code in Scala.
You may be used to old imperative loops *(for the way you name things, I assume you have a 
 Python background)* but **Scala** is not a another OOP language, it is a mix between FP and OOP.
And, even if Scala allows you to be imperative, you will find that the language provides you with [a lot of useful tools](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) to make the code simpler.

Some other mistakes include: bad syntax, the use of vectors instead of tuples to represent a tuple, and assuming you can always return a value.

A more idiomatic version of the code would be.

```
def inRange(start: Double, end: Double, x: Double): Boolean =
  x >= start && x < end

def findIndex(vectors: List[(Double, Double)])(x: Double): Option[Int] =
  vectors.iterator.zipWithIndex.collectFirst {
    case ((start, end), idx) if (inRange(start, end, x)) => idx
  }
```

*Side note, usually we do not use indexes that much. Maybe you actually want the tuple instead of the index of the tuple?*

Which you can use like:

```
findIndex(List((0, 3), (3, 5), (8, 10)))(3)
// res: Option[Int] = Some(1)
// A index was found.

findIndex(List((0, 3), (3, 5), (8, 10)))(6)
// res: Option[Int] = None
// A index was not found.
```

---

BTW, these are the kind of mistakes a person who is not following any actual Scala course and just reading the syntax would make. As I said before, this is not just another OOP language, you need more than syntax to understand and use Scala effectively, it requires a paradigm shift.

Comment: It feels like using `indexWhere` as suggested in my earlier answer is a better option ...

Comment: @Tim yeah, I didn't remember about that one and since you already answered with it, I decided not to edit my answer to use it. Anyways, I do not like the `-1` for when there is no match, but that is mainly a style / design choice.

Comment: Also _(start until end) contains x_ is better  than written a specific _inrange()_ function, imho